# Issue with css menu in internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've been working on a css menu and it works fine in every browser besides Internet Explorer.

The issue can bee seen below: The first `<li>` element is not properly aligned. In fact, it's pushed down.

[image]

```
#sub-navigation {
    background: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/subnavigation.png") repeat-x;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfeaf1;
    border-left: 1px solid #dfeaf1;
    border-right: 1px solid #dfeaf1;
    border-top: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
#second-navigation li {
    border-right: 1px solid #cddfeb;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    font-color: #6b6b6b;
}

#second-navigation ul {
    position: absolute; 
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #4e4e4e;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 80px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
<div id="sub-navigation">
        <ul id="second-navigation" class="leftside">
            <li>
                <a href="" title="Calendar"><center>Calendar</center>   </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" title="HH Converter">HH Converter</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" title="Poker Bonuses">Poker Bonuses</a>
            </li>
    </div>
```

Anyone know how to fix this, so it works in Internet Explorer.

Comment: IE version, please (to each its own bug-set)? assuming IE7 as it handles floating poorly.

Comment: Well, I haven't seen this error first hand as I'm on a mac, but one of the members on my site had this error in IE9.

Comment: attach the markup, too, please.

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) with some sample code that causes the issue? And is this issue being seen in any browser other than IE9?

Comment: I added the html (removed the links as im not allowed to post more then two), but i'll see if I can set up a Jsfiddle as well. I'm not sure if the error shows up in any other browser. I'm not able to test internet explorer on my own, I only know if someone lets me know

Comment: Well JSFiddle is under maintenance so i will have to wait before i can do that.

Comment: Could you add the html structure of the menu?

Comment: In IE, what you've given above works fine. Must be related to the wider markup/styles in some way. Can you post a link or put the whole menu on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't test the actual code for you at the moment. Test stations are being moved around. From experience and off the top of my head -- there are a few errors.

The code:

```
#sub-navigation {
    background: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/subnavigation.png") repeat-x;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfeaf1;
    border-left: 1px solid #dfeaf1;
    border-right: 1px solid #dfeaf1;
    border-top: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
#second-navigation ul {
    position: absolute; 
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #4e4e4e;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 80px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    list-style:none;
}
#second-navigation li {
    border-right: 1px solid #cddfeb;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: none;
    font-color: #6b6b6b;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#second-navigation li a {
    display:block;
}
#second-navigation .center {
    text-align:center;
}
<div id="sub-navigation">
        <ul id="second-navigation" class="leftside">
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Calendar" class="center">Calendar</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="HH Converter">HH Converter</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Poker Bonuses">Poker Bonuses</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The changes are:

- Unless you have a reset somewhere (like YUI Reset) ul and li should
  include a list-style: none; and list-style-type:none;
- On Internet Explorer, float:left; should be accompanied by
  display:inline-block; NOT display:block;
- On most browsers, elements within a p and a tag, will work... IE
  usually throws a hissy fit. Use CSS to declare a text-align center...
  which you should be doing anyways.

Hopefully this will help!

On a side note, CSS wise... if you are wanting the links centered and what not -- get rid of all the padding & margin write ups... browsers consider padding & margins differently and could be causing the issue.

A simple:

```
a {
display:block;
line-height: 25px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Would do the trick.